# Multiple OR Values in IF Statement

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Is the only way to do a value comparison against multiple values to list them all separately in an OR string?

Example:

```
if (@value == XXXX OR @value == XXXY OR @value == XXYY OR @value == XYYY) then
```

Or is there a more concise way to write the above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the case of just four possible matches, I would most likely do what you are already doing and just list them out and compare each. The solution below makes more sense if you have a ton of values to compare.

Here is a way to do this by using `BuildRowsetFromString()`. Our possible values are used as the first property of the `BuildRowsetFromString()` function and the delimiter is the second (Pipe in this case).

Then we loop through that rowset and in each loop we compare our `@value` to the field in that row.

In the code below, I'm setting `@matchedValue` to the matched value just to see which one actually matched, but you can have the other code you need in that same spot.

```
%%[
set @value = 'XXXY'
set @rowset = BuildRowsetFromString('XXXX|XXXY|XXYY|XYYY', '|')
for @i = 1 to Rowcount(@rowset) do
  set @name = Field(Row(@rowset, @i),1)

  if @name == @value then
    set @foundMatchedValue = true
    set @matchedValue = @name
  endif

next @i
]%%

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">  
  <tr><td>@i</td><td>%%=v(@i)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@value</td><td>%%=v(@value)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@foundMatchedValue</td><td>%%=v(@foundMatchedValue)=%%</td></tr>
  <tr><td>@matchedValue</td><td>%%=v(@matchedValue)=%%</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: To add on and make it more efficient, I would wrap the content in the FOR loop inside a conditoinal of `if @foundMatchedValue != true THEN` so that it won't run your code through the remaining values in your String rowset after finding a match which will increase processing speed and improve efficiency. You could technically also explore the SSJS do/while loop, but I wouldn't explore this unless you have a significantly large string rowset as SSJS is much slower than AMPscript.

Comment: In this case, each value is adding a line to the table, but I just want to show a single content piece if any of the found items exist--not create separate content for each item.

Comment: This is not adding separate content - you would use the `@foundMatchedValue` to turn on/off the the content you want.  E.g. `IF @foundMatchedValue THEN  /*Your matched content here*/ ELSE /*Your not a match content here*/ ENDIF`